# Calculating the number of trials necessary for even odds

Tags: probability, statistics

Abraham De Moivre gave a formula for finding how many trials are necessary to find even odds of a given even occurring at least once.

When $a$ is the odds of the event happening, and $b$ is the odds of it not happening, and $a:b=1:q$, then the equation can be written $(1+\frac{1}{q})^x=2$

For example - to determine when there are even odds of rolling 3 ones in a roll of three dice at least once you can solve for $x$ with $q=215$ (which is $6^3-1$).

How can I generalize this equation to find even odds of the event occuring at least twice, or three times etc?

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is based on the probability of it not happening in one attempt being  $\frac{q}{q+1}$ and so it not happening in $x$ attempts being $\left(\frac{b}{a+b}\right)^x=\left(\frac{q}{q+1}\right)^x$ which you set equal to $\frac12$ and solve for $x$ to give $x = \frac{\log(2)}{\log(a+b)-\log(b)} = \frac{\log(2)}{\log\left(1+\frac1q\right)}$.

Most $q$ will not give an integer result and your dice example has $x\approx 149.37$

For event occurring at least $n$ times you can do something similar with the cumulative distribution of a binomial distribution, though slightly more complicated, as you want to find the solution to $$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1} {x \choose j} \frac{a^jb^{x-j}}{(a+b)^x}=\frac12\text{, i.e. }\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1} {x \choose j} \frac{q^{x-j}}{(q+1)^x}=\frac12$$

Again most $q$ will not give an integer result for $x$, and this time I would not expect a closed from for $x$.

Comment: What do you mean by "closed from for x"?

Comment: I see how you have the same kind of formula over here, just because n is equal to one it simplifies things a lot. Why do you do x choose j?

Comment: @Burt See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression In the first example I gave a relatively simple $x= \cdots$ expression, but in the second I did not.  The binomial coefficient ${x \choose j}$ comes from using the binomial distribution for the probabilities